# Are there ways to customize Visual Studio code assistant?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Whenever I press <kbd>ctrl + space</kbd> in Visual Studio, it provides me a list of properties, methods, events, all that in a big list. Is there a way to filter the list to only show e.g. Events or Methods?

Also is there a way to filter out inherited stuff?